# AdMob for Android - how to obtain the app's "adUnitId"?

Tags: android

How do I obtain the `ads:adUnitId`?

I've created an account at AdMob, and I started to add my new app.
PROBLEM: I don't have an Android Package URL yet because, obviously, my app isn't ready to publish without the ads in it.

do I need to take this approach:

1. make up some adUnitID,
2. publish the app,
3. get the Android Package URL
4. finish the "Add Site/App" form with the Package URL
5. rebuild my app with the real `adUnitId` and re-publish

?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/06/android-how-to-add-admob-to-android-in.html and use the data from the images. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true you don't have an Android Package URL but the URL you'll get follows this "rule":

```
market://details?id=your.package.name
```

Same goes for the Play Store link it's everytime the same:

```
play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name
```

So even without publishing your app, you know which links your application is going to get as soon as it is published.

Comment: Question was "how to obtain the app's “adUnitId” - Your response has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: You better read the question again. He's clearly asking for the url so that he can obtain the adUnitId...

Comment: Wrong. He is NOT clearly asking for the package url. Read the title again of the posting. Sheesh, pretty obvious.

Comment: Maybe that's the difference between us. I don't just read the title I also read the actual question... Besides that: Since he accepted my answer I don't get your problem?

Comment: This answers is incorrect! :/ this is not related to ads:adUnitId

Comment: @Jorgesys I don't know how the setup procedure works nowadays but at the time of this question the OP asked how he can obtain the `ads:adUnitId` without having the URL. I told him what the URL will be based on his package name. Eventually he could create the correct adUnitId.